# Add Number for duplicate entry in sql

Tags: php, mysql

I have table like :-

```
ID               Name                 Email                     UserName
1               Johen mak         jojo@yahoo.com              Johen_mak
2               Johen mak         jojo@gmail.com              jojo
3               gawil gorgy       jojo@homail.com             gawil_gorgy
4               Johen mak         jojo@yamail.com             jojo
5               Johen mikik       jojo@yamail.com             jojo
```

In my table in database some entry is in same `UserName`, So i need to add _1 .... for end the `UserName`

I need to update above table like this:-

```
ID               Name                 Email                     UserName
1               Johen mak         jojo@yahoo.com              Johen_mak
2               Johen mak         jojo@gmail.com              jojo
3               gawil gorgy       jojo@homail.com             gawil_gorgy
4               Johen mak         jojo@yamail.com             jojo_1
5               Johen mikik       jojo@yamail.com             jojo_2
```

How can do that

Comment: What are you using to run your queries?

Comment: i try to update all UserName that have same value to add _1 on the end, see my second table in post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know that this solution don't answer exactly the problem you have but perhaps it help you:

```
UPDATE 
   TABLENAME T 
JOIN TABLENAME T2 
   ON T1.ID<T2.ID AND T1.Name = T2.Name
SET T2.NAME=CONCAT(T2.NAME,'_',T2.ID)
```

This will add _ID to the duplicates names after the first one

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that this is a symptom of a different issue - if you want user names to be unique, you should check the data before entering it into the database rather than after. Try adding a unique constraint on that row.

Comment: its not unique before ,Now i need to i try to update all UserName that have same value to add _1 on the end, see my second table in post

Answer (score 0):

Try below:

```
select a.ID,a.Name,a.Email,if((select count(*) from table b where a.username=b.username and a.ID>= b.ID) = 1,a.username,concat(a.username,'_',(select count(*) from table b where a.username=b.username and a.ID> b.ID))) as username from table a
```

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near

Comment: yes there was small sytax error. I have updated answer now you can try.